# Why i am not getting data after applying join query in table that doesnt have data?

Tags: sql, laravel

I have applied a join query on two tables.
One table has data but the other one does not.
When i try to join table that does not have data, it is not returning anything.
I expected data to come at least from the table which has data.

```
     $allTours = DB::table("virtual_tours")
                            ->join('destinations','virtual_tours.destination_id','=','destinations.id')
                            ->join('virtual_tour_comments','virtual_tours.id','=','virtual_tour_comments.virtual_tour_id')
                            ->get();
```

Virtual tour comments doensn't have data

Comment: Try to apply LEFT joining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a regular join, which becomes an inner join. Meaning data without a match on your conditions gets filtered out. Inner joins are meant to be used to find matches.

[Join explanations](https://www.diffen.com/difference/Inner_Join_vs_Outer_Join)

What you want is a left join, where data gets always joined but columns simply become NULL if they're not present and you'll get all results.

Since you're using laravel, here's the reference for it:

[Laravel Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins)

Comment: And to add: a RIGHT JOIN does the same thing, but from the other end of the join.

Comment: How can i count the data of left join in laravel db query?